# 'find -empty -delete' deletes non-empty directories

Tags: find

If I create the following directory structure:

```
mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

then I run `find dir1`, it returns:

```
dir1
dir1/dir2
dir1/dir2/dir3
dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

If I run `find dir1 -empty`, it returns only:

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

showing that only dir4 is empty.

However, if I run `find dir1 -empty -delete`, all four directories get deleted immediately.

I would expect only dir4 to be deleted, then the next time I ran the command, only dir3 would be deleted, and so on. Why does this happen, and how can I delete only dir4 using `find`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `-delete` implies `-depth`, or depth-first iteration, so `find` first looks at `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4`, notices it's empty, deletes it, then looks at `dir1/dir2/dir3`, notices it's (now) empty and deletes it...

[The GNU manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/findutils/find.1.en.html) says:

> `-depth`
> Process each directory's contents before the directory itself. The `-delete` action also implies `-depth`.

That's possibly they've considered that it's more commonly useful to be able to delete some files and then possibly the directory containing those files if it was emptied at the same time (`-delete` doesn't recursively remove the whole subtree), instead of having to repeat the `find` command until all matching files and directories are gone. Or looking at the other way, removing just the leaves of the tree (as we want here) isn't idempotent: running the command again by accident would strip another layer from the directory tree.

In any case, you could have `find` run `rmdir` instead to keep in the default mode, and add `-prune` to prevent it from trying to descend into the now-deleted directory. And let's add `-print` for debugging here too, so we see what it removes:

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
$ find -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \; -prune -print
./dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

and this is what remains:

```
$ find
.
./dir1
./dir1/dir2
./dir1/dir2/dir3
```

<sub>(Here, if the `rmdir` fails, the `-exec` action evaluates as falsy and the `-prune` and `-print` actions will not run. So the printout to stdout should only contain what was actually removed. This would be different with `-exec rmdir {} +`.)</sub>

Of course that assumes you only wanted to delete empty directories here, if you also want to delete empty files, you could do that first with

```
find -type f -empty -delete
```

Or build the awful combination that calls `rm` for files and `rmdir` for directories:

```
find -empty \( -type f -exec rm {} \; -o -type d -exec rmdir {} \; -prune \) -print
```

(`rm -rf` would also obviously work, but is riskier.)

Comment: _"I'm not exactly sure why it's like that, but it is."_ - If it wasn't, `find -delete -name foo\*` on `foo1/foo2` wouldn't remove `foo1/` because it is non-empty. I'd say that's unexpected behaviour if `foo1` only contains `foo2`.

Comment: @marcelm, right, I was thinking that `-prune` could also be an option, but of course that doesn't help there. Probably it's more useful depth-first since it makes the operation more likely to be idempotent, and doesn't result in people ending up running the same command repeatedly to catch all directories they wanted to delete...